# Notifying user when service returns, after routing to another component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services, angular2-observables, angular2-http

I have a service that takes too long to return. Once the user has submitted a request, he/she should be able to navigate to any other page.

How can I alert her that the request she submitted has been processed (the service has returned), regardless of which page he/she is currently in?

Comment: You mean another page within your service? IE navigating from `aaa.com/subpage` to `aaa.com/another-subpage`? Or navigating to different domain - from aaa.com to bbb.com?

Comment: @MaciejTreder, same app. Not another domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. You can create another component, let's say `alertBox` which would be added to your app skeleton:

```html
<alert-box></alert-box>
<div class="main">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Then you could have service:

```
export class MyService {
    private someObservable: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>();

    public makeSomeAction(): void {
        //some action
        this.someObservable.next('result');
    }

    public actionCompleted(): Observable<any> {
         return this.someObservable;
    }
}
```

injected into components:

```
@Component({})
export class ComponentOne {
    constructior(private _service: MyService) {}

    public someMethod() {
        this._service.makeSomeAction();
    }
}

@Component({})
export class AlertBox {
    constructior(private _service: MyService) {}

    public actionCompleted: void {
        this._service.actionCompleted.subscribe(() => console.log('action completed'));
    }
}
```

And you could handle your observables in this component.

2. Another solution is using `angular material`. There is a `snackbar` component which fits your needs perfectly: https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview

Example usage:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBar, MatSnackBarConfig } from '@angular/material';

@Injectable()
export class SnackBarService {

    constructor(private snackBar: MatSnackBar) {
    }

    public displayNotification(): void {
        const config: MatSnackBarConfig = new MatSnackBarConfig();
        config.duration = 1000; //time in ms

        this.snackBar.open("message", "action", config).afterDismissed().subscribe(() => {
             console.log('snackbar dismissed');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I get till adding an `alertComponent` to the main `app.component`. What do you mean by "you could handle your observables in this component"? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I have updated my answer. All in all I think that MdSnackbar is exactly what you are looking for. It would be easier to use ready solution, then write your own.

Comment: To clarify for others wondering, `MatSnackBar.open()` creates an HTML element that persists across `router.navigate()` calls.  So you can do things like open a snackbar that displays "login successful" while navigating the user to the page they were at before being prompted to login.